# Controlling and Profiling memory and time consumption C++ Windows Applications?

Tags: c++, windows, logging, profiling, runtime

Does anyone know a good and easy way of measuring (profiling) memory and processing time of a C++  applicationon Windows?
I wan't to make a grader, that will check my solutions if they are correct. It needs to tell me if the output generated by my source code is equal to the tests of a specific problem. If the program exceeds a specified time or memory limit, I will terminate it, and if not, I wish to log the time taken to execute the program and the memory usage during execution?

Are there any guides tutorials or code you can point me to or share with me to implement this?

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a profiler for your Windows C++ application, then I suggest Sleepy or [Very Sleepy](http://www.codersnotes.com/sleepy)

Comment: I'm not looking for a profiler... I'm looking for a program that I can use to test the time that passes and memory used during the runtime of some source code (solution to a programming task)... And if that time is greater than the time limit for execution of program to kill the process, and if the memory exceeds the memory limit in a problem to also kill the process. If you still don't understand what I mean, please take a look at some online judges like 
http://spoj.pl
http://z-trening.com
http://codeforces.com
and so on..